# How to make sendmail accept connections from localhost only

Tags: email, sendmail, spam

I need to secure the server by making sendmail-mta accept only local connections (from localhost), so that any external (potential spam) connections are denied.

I use Debian 7.0 currently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following line in your m4 config generation file will cause sendmail to listen to port 25 only on `127.0.0.1`:

```
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp,Addr=127.0.0.1, Name=MTA')dnl
```

Answer (score 1):

I decided to do it in another way. Instead of trying to tune the the sendmail-mta itself (which I did not succeed in) or recompiling it with the built-in options, I used a simple iptables rule:

iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 25 -j DROP

This rule blocks all incoming connections on ***eth0*** interface. The connections to the ***lo*** interface remain untouched.
  Of course, this is not a solution by means of the sendmail-mta, but it turned out to be much more simple to  solve this particular problem this way.

Comment: You're kidding, right?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: No, not at all. This is really the way I decided to solve my problem. But is it wrong?

Comment: It's kind of pointless, since the solution already given is so trivial. And, if your firewall gets dropped for some reason, you're back to being a potential spam relay.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Hm... Yes, you are right. If for some reason the firewall rule is not applied or flushed, it is pointless. I did not think of that. But as far as I understood from the previous answer, it requires recompiling the sendmail-mta daemon, doesn't it? But recompiling is not an easy way in my case. So is it the only *real* way to secure the mail-server? Thanks!

Comment: No, you just edit the `sendmail.mc` file and rebuild that (with `m4`). This is basic Sendmail.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Oh, sorry. I misunderstood all these from the very beginning. I just have never met such way of configuration before. Now I see that indeed my "self-answer" is completely pointless. I will mark the previous as "accepted" instead, since now I use this way. Thank you!